# Error al ingresar varias imagenes a la vez en MYSQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fileupload, upload

Utilizando una tabla de registros en mysql enlazada con una llave foranea a mi tabla imágenes deseo insertar a esta misma, varias imágenes a la vez en ese mismo registro. Esto lo intento hacer con un botón que envía el id del registro por metodo POST y se recibe para procesar una consulta.
Las imágenes se cargan a la Carpeta del Servidor pero No a la BDD (ruta), que estoy haciendo mal?

```
 <?php
 function con(){
return new mysqli("localhost","root","","mydb");
}
function insert_img($folder, $image){
$con = con();
$con->query("insert into imagenes (id_registro, folder, src, 
created_at) value (\"$id_registro\",\"$folder\",\"$image\",NOW())");
}
<?
```

upload.php

```
<?php
include "db.php";
include "class.upload.php";

/// mostrar errores
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$error = false;
$files = array();
foreach ($_FILES['imagenes'] as $k => $l) {
foreach ($l as $i => $v) {
if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
$files[$i] = array();
$files[$i][$k] = $v;
}
}
foreach ($files as $file) {
$handle = new Upload($file);
if ($handle->uploaded) {
$handle->Process("imagenes/");
if ($handle->processed) {
    // usamos la funcion insert_img de la libreria db.php
    insert_img("imagenes/",$handle->file_dst_name);
 } else {
  $error = true;
  echo 'Error: ' . $handle->error;
 }
 } else {
    $error = true;
echo 'Error: ' . $handle->error;
}
unset($handle);
}   
if(!$error){
print "<h4>Exito!</h4>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Dentro de la función `insert_img()` la variable `$id_registro` no está definida. Esto seguramente genere un warning en PHP y un error en la consulta SQL si es campo no es nulable.

Comment: Bien visto @Xerif ! Por otra parte, no hay necesidad de escribir la consulta así: `"insert into imagenes (id_registro, folder, src, 
created_at) value (\"$id_registro\",\"$folder\",\"$image\",NOW())"` se puede simplifcar: **`"insert into imagenes (id_registro, folder, src, created_at) value ($id_registro,'$folder','$image',NOW())"`** He asumido que la columna `id_registro` es numérica, por eso no la puede rodeada de comillas simples.

Comment: @A.Cedano Creo que tanto tú como yo iríamos un poco más allá y utilizaríamos sentencias preparadas que sería lo más adecuado. Pero si, es más legible utilizando comillas simples que escapar las dobles.

Comment: Claro @Xerif, así debería ser y no por gusto, sino por seguridad e incluso por rendimiento en el código.

Comment: Agradezco mucho sus observaciones @Xerif y A. Cedano , soy nueva en PHP y espero poder tener la lógica que ustedes tiene, de momento he realizado los cambios que me hicieron, pero siguen sin guardarse las rutas de las imágenes en la tabla de imágenes y me manda el siguiente error: "Undefined index: imagenes in www" de la siguiente linea -> foreach ($_FILES['imagenes'] as $k => $l) {

Comment: Qué podre estar haciendo mal @A. Cedano?

Comment: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; upload has a deprecated constructor in C:\wamp64\www\                      En la misma linea de código "foreach ($_FILES['imagenes'] as $k => $l) { "

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($_FILES['imagenes']);` y dinos lo que muestra, dinos también en qué clave se encuentra el dato que te interesa, ya que `$_FILES` podría traer varios datos.